# sequence of javascript events

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to serialize 2 events in my web application. I have change event tied to an input field and click event tied to a button. User sometimes enters value is input field and presses button immediately.

I want that change event should be called before click event.

Both of the events have AJAX calls and I have declared change event AJAX call as synchronous, but this does not help.

EDIT:
Other important details are as follows
I am using jQuery UI autocomplete feature related change event for input field.

Here is the portion of html code  along with related javascript code

```
<!-- I have more than one input fields with class set as code -->
<input type="text" name="code_1" id="code_1" class="code" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="code_2" id="code_2" class="code" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="code_3" id="code_3" class="code" value=""/>

<!-- Here is the clickable button -->
<input type="button" value="Save" class="formButton" id="postCharge"/>

// Here is the javascript code for these items

$(".code").autocomplete({
    source: jsHrefRoot+"/ajax/cpt_autocomp.php",
    minLength: 3,
    delay: 500,  // milliseconds - 1s = 1000ms
    select: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).val(ui.item.id);
      return false;
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
    // Following function has an AJAX call
      getCodeDetail($(this));
      return false;
    }
  }).each(function(){
    // This part is for rendering each item and not relevant to my question
  });


 $( "#postCharge" ).click(function(){
    // Again there is an AJAX call in this fuction after long logic of input validation
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one (async) way:

```
var $codeInputs = $('.code');
var $button = $('#postCharge');

function changeHandler (cb) {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        complete: function () {
            $(this).data('changeHandled', true);
            cb();
        }
    });
}

function clickHandler () {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
    });
}

function checkChanges (cb) {
    var $unhandled = $codeInputs.filter(function () {
        var hasChanged = $(this).val() !== $(this).data('initialValue');
        return hasChanged && !$(this).data('changeHandled');
    });

    if (!$unhandled.length) return cb();

    changeHandler.call($unhandled.first().get(), checkChanges.bind(this, cb));
}

$codeInputs.each(function () {
    $(this).data('initialValue', $(this).val());
})
.autocomplete({
    // ...
    change: function (event, ui) {
        changeHandler.call(this.get(), function () {
            // Ajax call complete
        });
    }
});

$button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    checkChanges(clickHandler.bind(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I delayed click event to wait for completion of autocomplete change.

```
function postCharges() {
  ...
  }
  $( "#postCharge" ).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(postCharges, 1000);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

change event always fire before click.

```
var cansubmit =true;
$('text').on('change',function(){
    cansubmit = false;
    $.ajax({
        ...
        complete:function(){
            cansubmit = true;
        }
    })
}
buildPromise=function(){
    new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var timer = null;
        function checkCanSubmit(){
            if(cansubmit){
               clearInterval(timer);
               resolve();
            }
        }
        if(cansubmit)
              resolve();
        else
              timer = setInterval(checkCanSubmit,10);
    })
}
$('btn').on('click',function(){
    buildPromise().then(function(){
        //todo::
    })
})
```